# Before making DCT on an image,should I make the pixel value in [-128,127] instead of the original range [0,255]?

Tags: image-processing, dct

I want to extract features of some images in the DCT domain.I wonder if it is necessary to change the range of pixel value into [-128,127] which is original in a range of [0,255]? Are there some differences of the results between these two methods? I would really appreciate if someone can help me!

Comment: It wouldn't matter for any DCT component other than zeroth anyway.

Comment: Why do you need a range of [-128,127] in the first place?

Comment: That matters only if you are very close to number representation limits to ease up one bit ... but most DCT implementations are on floating point anyway so no need to bother with this ....

Comment: Thanks a lot for you guys answering me the question.It is really helpful.Now I can continue my experiment without bothering with this ! ^_^